# How to apply value_counts across the index and create new dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'name': {0: 'Silvers Park', 1: 'Adare Road', 2: 'Cargo Road'}, 
'type_2': {0: 'Secondary', 1: 'Special', 2: 'Secondary'}, 
'type_3': {0: 'Nursery', 1: nan, 2: nan}, 
'type_4': {0: 'Primary', 1: nan, 2: nan}, 
'type_5': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan}, 
'type_6': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan}
})



                       name      type_2     type_3   type_4  type_5 type_6
0                 Silvers Park  Secondary   Nursery  Primary   NaN    NaN
1                  Adare Road     Special      NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
2                  Cargo Road   Secondary      NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
```

**Desired Outcome:**

I would like to transform the above df so a count of schools type per road is presented. The unique values (variables required) are represented in the below dataframe columns.

For example:

```
                      name     Secondary     Special   Primary  Nursery 
0                 Silvers Park      1           0           1         1 
1                  Adare Road       0           1           0         0
2                  Cargo Road       1           0           0         0
```

Thank you in advance.

pandas 0.23.4

python 3.7.1

Comment: There were some inconsistencies with the data, so I've fixed it for you. If there's some issue, rollback and let me know.

Comment: Thansk @coldspeed -  correction is valid, my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `melt` your data, then pivot with `pivot_table`:

```
u = df.melt('name')
u.pivot_table(index='name', columns='value', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

value         Nursery  Primary  Secondary  Special
name                                              
Adare Road          0        0          0        1
Cargo Road          0        0          1        0
Silvers Park        1        1          1        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with remove only `NaN`s columns, if possible duplicates add `sum`:

```
df = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('name')
                      .dropna(how='all', axis=1), prefix_sep='',prefix='')
        .sum(axis=1, level=0)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
           name  Secondary  Special  Nursery  Primary
0  Silvers Park          1        0        1        1
1    Adare Road          0        1        0        0
2    Cargo Road          1        0        0        0
```